# HighCharts - How can i use the period separator in xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highchart for statistics with xaxis type categories and i wanna the xaxis separate in range

I want to add this small separator like in the phots
[image: What i want to achieve]

What i have
[image: What i have]

Here's the code that i'm using , for the first photo i use the accessiblity with rangeDescription
accessibility: {
rangeDescription: 'Range: 2010 to 2017'
}
But here i want to use xaxis : {type : 'category'}

````
  chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

  title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
  },

  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
      categories :[2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017]
  },

  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      label: {
        connectorAllowed: false
      },
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
  }, {
    name: 'Sales & Distribution',
    data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
  }, {
    name: 'Project Development',
    data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
  }, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
  }],

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxWidth: 500
      },
      chartOptions: {
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
      }
    }]
  }

});```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `tickWidth` property and set `tickmarkPlacement` to `on`:

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: [...],
    tickWidth: 1,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/580upzk7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis